# quick.db leveling system - database.updateValue is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, quick.db

I'm trying to make a leveling system with a discord bot using quick.db. I've been working with this for a while and couldn't figure it out so I figured I'd go here. My current code is:
(app.js)

```
    //Message Leveling
    database.updateValue(message.author.id + message.guild.id, 1).then(i => {


        let messages;
        if (i.value = 25) messages = 25; // Level 1
        else if (i.value == 50) messages = 50; // Level 2
        else if (i.value == 75) messages = 75; //Level 3

        if (!isNaN(messages)) { // If messages iss STILL empty, run this
            database.updateValue(`userLevel_${message.author.id + message.guild.id}`, 1).then(o => {
                message.channel.send(`You sent ${messages} messages, LEVEL UP HOME BOY! level ${o.value}`)
            })
        }
    })
```

(messages.js)

```
const db = require('quick.db');
var database = require('quick.db')

exports.run = (bot, message, args, func) => {

    database.fetchObject(message.author.id + message.guild.id).then(i => {
        database.fetchObject(`userLevel_${message.author.id + message.guild.id}`).then(o => {
            message.channel.send('Messages sent: `' + (i.value + 1) + '`\nLevel: `' + o.value +'`');

        })
    })

}
```

Now, the error I get happens in app.js but I figured the code from messages.js might be helpful. The error is:

```
[help]     database.updateValue(message.author.id + message.guild.id, 1).then(i => {
[help]              ^
[help]
[help] TypeError: database.updateValue is not a function
```

Being new to this I still don't quite understand what a TypeError is or how to fix it, despite looking it up on google (I know, I'm a real researcher). So I was hoping someone could give me a hand. I also couldn't find an example of this error, so I'm pretty lost.

As always, thanks for taking the time to read my question, if I got any terminology wrong feel free to ask me about what I mean, or you can just call me stupid.
<3

Comment: quick.db doesn't have updateValue function

Comment: Seems like you might want to look at .set(key, data) [here](https://quickdb.js.org/docs.html#set-method)

Answer (score 0):

`database.updateValue` isn't a function, instead you would want to use `database.add`like:

```
    database.add(`level_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`, 1).then(i => {


    let messages;
    if (i.value = 25) messages = 25; // Level 1
    else if (i.value == 50) messages = 50; // Level 2
    else if (i.value == 75) messages = 75; //Level 3

    if (!isNaN(messages)) { // If messages iss STILL empty, run this
        database.add(`level_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}`, 1).then(o => {
            message.channel.send(`You sent ${messages} messages, LEVEL UP HOME BOY! level ${o.value}`)
        })
    }
})
```

For fetching databases, `fetchObject` isn't a function, use `fetch` or `get`

```
const db = require('quick.db');
var database = require('quick.db')

exports.run = (bot, message, args, func) => {

db.fetch(level_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}).then(i => {
    db.fetch(level_${message.guild.id}_${message.author.id}).then(o => {
        message.channel.send('Messages sent: `' + (i.value + 1) + '`\nLevel: `' + o.value +'`');

    })
})

}
```

If you've defined `quick.db` as `db` then instead of calling `database`, call `db` otherwise it just wouldn't work.

Thanks,
Chills